# JQuery add class on scroll height header

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I use this code to add a class on scroll. The active class works great, but the location on the page when the class is placed is not correct. We use a main header on our website with position fixed and when this header becomes sticky it is placed below our main header also fixed. The active class needs to be placed earlier on the page when scroll, because the content of the section already started, when the class is placed.

And for some reason the code conflicts with another script on the same page, how can I fix that problem? That both scripts with beside each other.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0knrcv3z/1/

HTML:

```
<div style="height:57px;">
  <div class="menu-header-product">
  <div class="product-anchor-links-wrapper">
  <nav class="product-page-nav">
   <ul class="menu-header-top-product">
    <li class="menu-item-header-product"><a href="#description" class="product-nav-link">Productbeschrijving</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item-header-product"><a href="#additional" class="product-nav-link">Specificaties</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item-header-product"><a href="#reviews" class="product-nav-link">Reviews</a></li>
   </ul>
  </nav>
 </div>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="content">  
<section id="description">
<div class="box-description"></div>
</section>

<section id="additional">
<div class="box-additional"></div>
</section>

<section id="reviews">
<div class="box-reviews"></div>
</section>
</div>
```

What do I need to change in this code?

```
<script>
$(window).scroll(function(){
  var sticky = $('.menu-header-product'),
      scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

  if (scroll >= 645) sticky.addClass('sticky');
  else sticky.removeClass('sticky');
});
$(window).scroll(function(){
  var sticky = $('.content'),
      scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

  if (scroll >= 645) sticky.addClass('sticky');
  else sticky.removeClass('sticky');
});
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);

        $('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(document).off("scroll");

            $('a').each(function () {
                $(this).removeClass('active');
            })
            $(this).addClass('active');

            var target = this.hash;
            $target = $(target);
            $('html, body').stop().animate({
            'scrollTop': $target.offset().top-130 /**just subtract the height of the fixed html part */
             }, 500, 'swing', function () {
                window.location.hash = target;
                $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);
            });
        });
    });

function onScroll(event){
        var scrollPosition = $(document).scrollTop();
        $('nav a').each(function () {
            var currentLink = $(this);
            var refElement = $(currentLink.attr("href"));
            if (refElement.position().top <= scrollPosition && refElement.position().top + refElement.height() > scrollPosition) {
                $('nav ul li a').removeClass("active");
                currentLink.addClass("active");
            }
            else{
                currentLink.removeClass("active");
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Can you wrap things up in a working Fiddle or snippet ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if (**scroll >= 50**) sticky.addClass('sticky');   else
>   sticky.removeClass('sticky'); }); $(window).scroll(function(){   var
>   sticky = $('.content'),
>         scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
>
> if (**scroll >= 12**) sticky.addClass('sticky');   else
>   sticky.removeClass('sticky'); });

adds the sticke header when scrolling over "50" and removes it wenn scrolling under 12. just edit those numbers as long as it would be good for you ;)

Comment: Can you edit the Fiddle with this code? Because I tried it, but the code did not work.

Comment: i just edited it a little bit, but it isn't perfect.. i'll look for another thing to fix it

Comment: Tried that, but that code is not bringing me the solution. Do you know another solution?

Comment: Fixed it! 

Chanced this `if (refElement.position().top <= scrollPosition && refElement.position().top + refElement.height() > scrollPosition) {`

into 

`if (refElement.position().top - 130 <= scrollPosition && refElement.position().top - 130 + refElement.height() > scrollPosition) {`